# ArgumentError - bad value for range

Tags: ruby

Looks like the Range method has been enhanced in Ruby, I'm using v2.5.1 and it's not working as expected. This was working before, but now is not working.

I have this line of code:

```
@events = Event.where(start: params[:start]..params[:ends])
```

And the start and ends symbols are expecting a date value. Here's the log in my rails console.

```
Started GET "/events.json?start=2018-05-27&end=2018-07-08&_=1529068714340" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-06-15 16:18:34 +0300
Processing by EventsController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"start"=>"2018-05-27", "end"=>"2018-07-08", "_"=>"1529068714340"}
```

But I'm getting this error in the console -

```
ArgumentError - bad value for range:
  app/controllers/events_controller.rb:7:in `index'
```

Please, how can I get the proper range?

Here's the repo incase you want to check it out - https://github.com/mayordwells/fullcalendar-rails-demo

Comment: What of you converted the params to date types before forming the range? I'm surprised a string would ever work in that scenario.

Comment: @lurker I tested it in Rails 4 with PostgreSQL and it generated the same SQL with a string range or a data range ... Rails magic I guess.

Comment: At some point it needs to convert before attemptimg to create a range on string values. Perhaps for some reason on your prior version it knew to do the conversion implicitly. Nothing else has changed except Rails version?

Comment: @lurker ranges accept string values. the values between `"2018-05-27"` and `"2018-07-08"` are not necessarily dates but ruby can handle the increment in this case (essentially it ignores the hyphens and increments from `20180527` through `20180708` as for @DavidAldridge's comment I am pretty sure range just uses `begin` and `end` for Between queries and most SQL can use the Date formatted as a String for query conditions.

Comment: @engineersmnky that's interesting. I suppose not all that surprising after all in Rails.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a parameter with `params[:ends]` but your parameter is `"end"=>"2018-07-08"`.

`ends` vs `end`

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform string parameters into Date objects

```
Date.parse(params[:start])..Date.parse(params[:ends])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this didn't work. 
Started GET "/events.json?start=2018-05-27&end=2018-07-08&_=1529071409292" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-06-15 17:03:29 +0300
Processing by EventsController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"start"=>"2018-05-27", "end"=>"2018-07-08", "_"=>"1529071409292"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Got this error

TypeError - no implicit conversion of nil into String:
  app/controllers/events_controller.rb:5:in `parse'
  app/controllers/events_controller.rb:5:in `index'

Comment: Here's what i tried - @events = Event.where(start: Date.parse(params[:start])..Date.parse(params[:ends]))

Comment: @mayorsanmayor: look __very__ closely at what you are requesting from `params` and what actually is there. Do all `params[xxx]` return what you think they do?

Comment: Yes all params are returning what is needed except that the range is not applying to them, i have added the repo in my question for check. Please take a look. Thanks

Comment: @mayorsanmayor: Yes all params are returning what is needed" - are they, though? Did you check? I don't think so. See David's answer.

Comment: Haaa, that’s a stupid mistake. Thank you very much for pointing that out. Will try and fix that now and then update you.

Comment: @mayorsanmayor: for the future, when you are asked to do something by a seemingly-knowledgeable user, just do that. In this particular case I was trying to teach a basic debugging technique: making hyphotheses and challenging them. I use it several times a day, every day.

Comment: You are right I wasn’t paying enough attention. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: They don't *need* to transform the strings into dates...it's likely they'd want to, but `[*"2018-05-27".."2018-07-08"]` works just fine* (*for certain definitions of fine)

Comment: @SimpleLime the decomposition via splat `*` would actually be detrimental in this case as a `Range` will result in a `BETWEEN` query condition where as an `Array` will result in an `IN` condition. The `IN` condition in this case would contain nonsensical values such as `"2018-06-99"` which is clearly not a valid date but is a valid range value in this case